# Multiple PHP file read to produce alternating rows for html table

Tags: php

I have to create a multiple alternating rows that contain different sets of data from different text documents. I can read text files okay I just cant figure out how I would do the  alternating rows using the different queries in one html table.

I have thought about storing the data in a database, might this be a better way to go rather than reading in a text file every time the page loads?

What other ways could I achieve the output, I have currently looked at a previous thread [Selecting alternating records from two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419264/selecting-alternating-records-from-two-tables) but it didn't seem applicable due to it using a database to produce the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a record of which line you're processing and use the modulus operator:

```
$LineNumber = 1;
while ()
{
    if (($LineNumber % 2) == 1) // Is odd
        $SecondaryTable .= "<td>I feel odd</td>";
    else
        $PrimaryTable .= "<td>hello</td>";

    $LineNumber++;
}

// ... Finish off the tables here

echo $PrimaryTable;
echo $SecondaryTable;
```